# Curl get url with curl_getinfo

Tags: php, curl

Hi I know its a very common topic on StackOverFlow. I have already spent my entire week to search it out.

Such as I have a url : http://bayja.com/forum/index.php

This url I want to get after I post : http://bayja.com/forum/index.php?topic=3454.0

but now I get http://bayja.com/forum/index.php?board=2.0

I use `$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`

How can I get "http://bayja.com/forum/index.php?topic=3454.0
" ?

Please help me thank you.

here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Automatic SMF poster thing");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=".$user."&passwrd=".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$domain?action=login2");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$domain?action=post;board=".$board.".0");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
sleep(3);
preg_match('/name="([^"]+)" value="([^"]{32})"/',$data,$sc);
preg_match ( "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"seqnum\" value=\"(.*)\">", $data, $seqnum);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "topic=".$topic."&subject=".urlencode($subj)."&icon=xx&sel_face=&sel_size=&sel_color=&message=".urlencode($mess)."&message_mode=0&notify=0&lock=0&post_vv[q][4]=๔&post_vv[q][3]=๒&post_vv[q][1]=๔&post_vv[q][2]=๒&additional_options=0&post=xxxxx&".$sc[1]."=".$sc[2]."&seqnum=4&seqnum=".$seqnum[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$domain?action=post2;start=0;board=".$board);
curl_exec($ch);
 $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
 echo $lastUrl; // output "http://bayja.com/forum/index.php?board2" 
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: have you got any solution?